# How to create two columns having cumulative sum based on a column value and having group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having following dataframe in pandas using python3.7

```
data = {'s':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
        'cp':['C','P','C','C','C','P'],
        'st':[300,300,300,300,310,310],
         'qty':[3000,3000,3000,6000,9000,3000],
         'p':[16,15,14,10,8,12]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['t']=df['p']*df['qty']
df['ct']=df['t'].cumsum()
df

s   cp  st  qty p   t   ct
0   a   C   300 3000    16  48000   48000
1   a   P   300 3000    15  45000   93000
2   a   C   300 3000    14  42000   135000
3   a   C   300 6000    10  60000   195000
4   b   C   310 9000    8   72000   267000
5   b   P   310 3000    12  36000   303000
```

I want to create two separate columns say x and y based on S, and CP Values having cummulative sum of qty

```
col x = cumm qty where cp="c" group by col s
col y = cumm qty where cp=P group by col s

    s   cp  st  qty p   t   ct                x      y
0   a   C   300 3000    16  48000   48000     3000     0
1   a   P   300 3000    15  45000   93000     3000   3000
2   a   C   300 3000    14  42000   135000    6000   3000
3   a   C   300 6000    10  60000   195000   12000   3000
4   b   C   310 9000    8   72000   267000    9000     0
5   b   P   310 3000    12  36000   303000    9000   3000

I tried something like this

df['x']=df.loc[df['p']>0].groupby(['s'])['s','cp','qty','ct'].apply(lambda x:x['qty'].cumsum() if x['cp']=="C" else 0)
```

It is giving following error
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am also not sure where it will give me expected output. Can you pl help me ?

Comment: I tried this, it is giving cumsum in one column I want separate two columns one where having cp value "C" another cp value "P"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df['X']=df.where(df['cp'].eq('C')).groupby('s')['qty'].cumsum().fillna(df['qty'])
df['Y']=0
df.loc[~df['cp'].shift(-1).eq('P'),'Y']=df.loc[df['cp'].eq('P'),'qty']
df=df.ffill()
```

---

```
     s   cp  st  qty p   t   ct                x      y
0   a   C   300 3000    16  48000   48000     3000     0
1   a   P   300 3000    15  45000   93000     3000   3000
2   a   C   300 3000    14  42000   135000    6000   3000
3   a   C   300 6000    10  60000   195000   12000   3000
4   b   C   310 9000    8   72000   267000    9000     0
5   b   P   310 3000    12  36000   303000    9000   3000
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but your code is not giving correct value for s value changed for e.g.

Comment: b c 310 9000 8 72000 267000 it should have values 9000, 0 and for x and y and for next row x and y values should be 9000 3000

Comment: Your solution for x e and I don't understand how you get them, I think they are wrong. I don't understand what the criteria is

Comment: column x = cumm sum of qty where cp="C" but it should to cumm sum as per s value column y is same like x except value is "P". e.g value of s is a, cp is C qty=10 (first row ) then x, y should be 10, 0 second row values are a, P, 20 then x and y for second row should be 10, 20 third row values are b, C, 15 then x and y should be 15, 0 4th row values are a, C, 8 then values should be 18, 20 hopefully clearly explained

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check it. One question does equality requires eq as mentioned f['cp'].eq('C')) or it can be checked as == also ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution

```
df['x'] = df['qty'].mul(df['cp'].eq('C')).groupby(df['s']).cumsum()
df['y'] = df['qty'].mul(df['cp'].eq('P')).groupby(df['s']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   s cp   st   qty   p      t      ct      x     y
0  a  C  300  3000  16  48000   48000   3000     0
1  a  P  300  3000  15  45000   93000   3000  3000
2  a  C  300  3000  14  42000  135000   6000  3000
3  a  C  300  6000  10  60000  195000  12000  3000
4  b  C  310  9000   8  72000  267000   9000     0
5  b  P  310  3000  12  36000  303000   9000  3000
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it is working. Great help.  Can you pl explain why you used mul? can it be also done np.where  or lambda ?

Comment: mul means multiply, so you mask the `C` as 1 and `P` as 0.